# Obtener el cuarto numero de numeros separados por ; con expresiones regulares java

Tags: java, regex

Estoy intentando buscar el número que esta en la posición cuarta de una cadena de numeros separados por punto y coma

La cadena de ejemplo es la siguiente:

```
84;29.02964;28.87731;25.28935;0;-0.1523228;3.735915;27;27;349;27;27;413;27;27;371;26;26;373;26;26;420;27;27;381;242;402;373;345;420;443;264;431;400;229;381;361;324;446;430;274;424;396;726.5;760;5.14;0;6.19;4.99;0;5.57;5.02;0;4.96;5.06;0;5.03;4.9;0.01;5;5.02;0;5.03;8.17;0;4.84;8.48;0;5.21;3.72;0;6;6.17;0.01;3.83;3.83;0;5.72;4.01;0;5.13;0.01;6.05;0;0;0;0.01;0;6.02;0.02;0;0;8.16;0;5.76;0.01;0;0.01;10.01;0.02;5.9;0.01;0;0;0;0.02;4.34;0.01;7.76;0;0.02;0;5.96;0.02;0;0;0.01;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;757;
```

Lo he intantedo con

```
 *[\-\d\;]**
```

Pero logicamente no funciona.

¿Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: y porque hacerlo con Regex? tenes alguna obligacion de eso? proque es mas facil buscarlo posicionalmente...

Comment: si sabes que la cadena se va a comportar de manera que va a almacenar los numeros separados por ; puedes separarla por ese delimitador y tomar la cuarta posición, incluso puedes separar incluso una subcadena comensando por el comienzo asi no tienes ke splitear toda la cadena

Comment: Jesús, no indicas si hay que validar si los números son correctos o si realmente sólo te interesa lo que está en cuarta posición y el hecho de que sean números es lo de menos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución simple:

```
String cadena = "84;29.02964;28.87731;25.28935;0;-0.1523228;3.735915;27;27;349;27;27;413;27;27;371;26;26;373;26;26;420;27;27;381;242;402;373;345;420;443;264;431;400;229;381;361;324;446;430;274;424;396;726.5;760;5.14;0;6.19;4.99;0;5.57;5.02;0;4.96;5.06;0;5.03;4.9;0.01;5;5.02;0;5.03;8.17;0;4.84;8.48;0;5.21;3.72;0;6;6.17;0.01;3.83;3.83;0;5.72;4.01;0;5.13;0.01;6.05;0;0;0;0.01;0;6.02;0.02;0;0;8.16;0;5.76;0.01;0;0.01;10.01;0.02;5.9;0.01;0;0;0;0.02;4.34;0.01;7.76;0;0.02;0;5.96;0.02;0;0;0.01;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;757;";
String cuarto = cadena.split(";")[3];
log(cuarto); // 25.28935
```

[El método `split` de `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) usa una expresión regular para dividir la cadena de texto y devuelve un Array de texto. De allí sólo seleccionas el cuarto elemento (índice 3) que es el que necesitas.

Comment: Nery, aunque tu respuesta es correcta, fijate que OP pidio que fuera con regex, y el primer comentario que le deje fue preguntandole si tenia que hacerlo de esa forma por algun motivo. La proxima vez, antes de apurarte a contestar, fijate que dice el usuario al respecto.

Comment: @gbianchi Cuando comencé a escribir la respuesta no estaba tu comentario.

Comment: no hay problema. tambien podias preguntarselo ;)

Comment: Entiendo.... En todo caso, el método `split` pide expresiones regulares, en ese caso `";"` sería considerada una expresion regular normal. Actualizo la respuesta para aclarar.

Comment: Genial! mucho mejor asi ;)